# hover over div and make another div change color

Tags: html, css

If I hover over div `#id1`  I want to make div `#match3` change color. Why does this not work?

I DO NOT WANT TO USE JAVASCRIPT only css.

http://jsfiddle.net/fA2gv/1/

html

```
<div id="id1">DIV</div> 
<div id="id2">DIV</div> 
<div id="id3">DIV</div> 


<div id="match1">a </ div>
<div id="match2">b </ div>
<div id="match3">c </ div>
```

css

```
#id1:hover ~ #match3 {

color:red;    

}
```

Comment: Drop the spaces before closing tag names and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div id="match1">a </ div>
```

You need to remove the space in the closing tag.

```
<div id="match1">a </div>
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fA2gv/7/

Answer (score 2):

Your `div` tags are not completely closed..

```
<div id="id1">DIV</div>
<div id="id2">DIV</div>
<div id="id3">DIV</div>
<div id="match1">a</div>
<div id="match2">b</div>
<div id="match3">c</div>
```

shall work: http://jsfiddle.net/fA2gv/5/

Answer (score 2):

It works, except that you need to Change `</ div>` to `<div>`

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fA2gv/3/)

Answer (score 2):

You have invalid HTML. Remove the spaces in `</ div>`:

```
<div id="id1">DIV</div> 
<div id="id2">DIV</div> 
<div id="id3">DIV</div> 


<div id="match1">a </div>
<div id="match2">b </div>
<div id="match3">c </div>
```

***Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/fA2gv/6/*